dnsmasq failed to start following update to ubuntu server 24.04.1 from 22.04
I upgraded my ubuntu server from 22.04 to 24.04.1. Upon a reboot i saw that dnsmasq failed to start. I found that this was because it was sharing port 53 with systemd-resolved. So i went into the config file for resolved and set DNSStubListener=no This solved this issue.
Now the status of dnsmasq is showing the following error:
Sep 04 09:13:34 paveycloud.com resolvconf[27804]: Dropped protocol specifier '.dnsmasq' from 'lo.dnsmasq'. Using 'lo' (ifindex=1).
Sep 04 09:13:34 paveycloud.com resolvconf[27804]: Failed to set DNS configuration: Link lo is loopback device.
Please can someone help track down this error.

I found that I had to edit the file /etc/default/dnsmasq and uncomment the following lines:
IGNORE_RESOLVCONF=yes
DNSMASQ_EXCEPT="lo"

I also had to add:
bind-interface
interface=bond0 (the interface that will be providing the DHCP)

So this appears to tell dnsmasq not to use resolvconf as the resolver as the system is now using systemd-resolved.
Once dnsmasq.service was restarted, everything works as it should.

do you have the resolvconf package installed?

@SpinUp__ADavis No. As I say resolvconf has been replaced by systemd-resolved. I did try to reinstall resolvconf via apt but I got the message Note, selecting 'systemd-resolved' instead of 'resolvconf'

I see, resolvconf is a virtual package now, at least in Ubuntu. Good to know. I'm about to do the LTS upgrade myself, so I'll probably need to make a similar change.

@SpinUp__ADavis If you get some failure messages from dnsmasq after the upgrade, you may have the same issue I had. It's strange that I couldn't find any useful information on-line about these error messages. So it seems like this failure mode is quite uncommon, or my configuration is not standard. Good luck.
